# not able to compile android microsoft CRM SDK

Tags: android, gradle, dynamics-crm

not able to compile `android Microsoft CRM SDK`

source [Android Microsoft CRM SDK](https://github.com/DynamicsCRM/crm-mobilesdk-library-for-android)
[image]

when i compile i am getting following error

I have set my environment variables as follows

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Nihar/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA8_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA7_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```